# What are the differences in table partitioning features in SQLServer vs MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-partitioning

I used to work with MySQL and have moved into a product that uses SQL Server as their back end.

MySQL supports several [types of partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-types.html).

What does SQL Server support? And how does it compare?

Comment: just search for Row_number,Rank,Dense_Rank,NTILE in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server table partitioning is fundamentally range partitioning.  List partitioning can be implemented as range partition boundaries plus a check constraint for exact values.  Hash and key partitioning can be implemented by creating a computed column with the desired hash or key and then using that as the partitioning column.